# AutoCAD Rotate Group Using Reference Angle VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, autocad

I’m trying to rotate a group of objects using a specified reference angle, however my code below always uses 0 as the reference angle. Hoping someone can help me out with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
<CommandMethod("ROTATEGROUP")>
        Public Shared Sub ROTATEGROUP()

            Dim doc As Document = AutoCADApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
            Dim db As Database = doc.Database
            Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor

            Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

                Dim GroupName As String = ed.GetString("Group Name").StringResult
                Dim X As Single = ed.GetString("X").StringResult
                Dim Y As Single = ed.GetString("Y").StringResult
                Dim Z As Single = ed.GetString("Z").StringResult
                Dim RefAngle As Single = ed.GetString("Refence Angle").StringResult * (Math.PI / 180)
                Dim NewAngle As Single = ed.GetString("New Angle").StringResult * (Math.PI / 180)

                Dim bt As BlockTable = CType(tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead), BlockTable)
                Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = TryCast(tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), OpenMode.ForWrite), BlockTableRecord)
                Dim gd As DBDictionary = CType(tr.GetObject(db.GroupDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead), DBDictionary)
                Dim grpId As ObjectId = gd.GetAt(GroupName)
                Dim grp As Group = CType(tr.GetObject(grpId, OpenMode.ForWrite), Group)
                Dim ids As ObjectId() = grp.GetAllEntityIds()

                Dim curUCSMatrix As Matrix3d = doc.Editor.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem
                Dim curUCS As CoordinateSystem3d = curUCSMatrix.CoordinateSystem3d

                For i As Integer = 0 To ids.Length - 1
                    Dim ent As Entity = CType(tr.GetObject(ids(i), OpenMode.ForWrite), Entity)

                    ent.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Rotation(NewAngle, curUCS.Zaxis, New Point3d(X, Y, Z)))
                Next

                'Save to the database
                tr.Commit()

            End Using
        End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you declared `NewAngle` as a String?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It should be Single.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation angle should be: NewAngle - RefAngle.
You should use [GetPoint](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=OARX-ManagedRefGuide-__OVERLOADED_GetPoint_Autodesk_AutoCAD_EditorInput_Editor) and [GetAngle](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=OARX-ManagedRefGuide-__OVERLOADED_GetAngle_Autodesk_AutoCAD_EditorInput_Editor) instead of GetString.